# Where can one find free look-ups in the Ohio Genealogical Report?

Tags: united-states, ohio

Does anyone know of a website where you can request free look-ups in back issues of *The Ohio Genealogical Report*?

Answer (score 3):

All back issues of the *Ohio Genealogical Society Report* (1961-2003) and *Ohio Genealogical Society Quarterly* (2003-present) are accessible online to members of the [Ohio Genealogical Society](http://www.ogs.org/journals/index.php).

The [OGS membership fee](http://www.ogs.org/membership/index.php) is currently $35 per year, which provides you with access to these journals and much more.

If there is one specific article you require, OGS may provide you with a copy for a nominal fee if you contact them.

You might also try one of the [Ohio RAOGK volunteers](http://www.raogk.org/lookups/region/ohio/) – some of them note they have access to a local OGS chapter. You would be expected to reimburse the volunteer for any copying and mailing costs.